# Is there a generalisation of this perturbation result about rank-one modifications of diagonal matrices?

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, perturbation-theory

In Theorem 1 of [1] we have the following result: Let $D$ be a real $n \times n$ diagonal matrix and consider the rank-one modification $C = D + \rho z z^T$, where $\rho > 0$ is a real scalar and $z$ is a real vector such that $\|z\| = 1$. Let $d_1 \le d_2 \le \dotsm \le d_n$ be the eigenvalues of $D$ and $c_1 \le c_2 \le \dotsm \le c_n$ be the eigenvalues of $C$. Then, for all $k = 1,\dotsc,n$, we have
$$
c_k = d_k + \rho \mu_k\,, \quad \text{with } \mu_k \ge 0 \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k = 1\,. 
$$
Moreover, we have the following interlacing
$$
d_1 \le c_1 \le d_2 \le \dotsm \le d_n \le c_n\,.
$$
Now, instead of a real symmetric rank-one perturbation, consider $C = D + i \rho z z^\ast$, where $z$ is now a complex vector, $i$ is the imaginary unit and the asterisk denotes the complex conjugate transpose ($\rho$ is still real). The rank-one perturbation is now skew-hermitian and the eigenvalues of $C$ can now contain a non-zero imaginary part.

My Question is: Is there a version of the result above for this case?

I did a few numerical examples and found the theorem to be still true (except for the part $\mu_k \ge 0$ which no longer makes sense, since the $\mu_k$ are now complex; but it seems that their real parts satisfy this and also the real parts of the eigenvalues seem to satisfy the interlacing property).
Maybe there are also other results, not specific to rank-one modifications, such as Weyl-type inequalities that can be adapted to this case.

[1] J. Bunch, C. Nielsen and D. Sorensen: Rank-One Modificaton of the Symmetric Eigenproblem. Numer. Math. vol. 31, pp. 31 - 48, 1978. URL: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396012.

Comment: I don't know the answer, off the top of my head, but the interlacing property reminded me of a talk by Cynthia Vinzant on hyperbolic polynomials.